# What will the following year tax burden be on partial repay of an premature 401K withdrawal?

Tags: taxes, 401k, withdrawal

What will the following year tax burden be on partial repay of an premature 401K withdrawal?

I quit my job.
I have a 401K from the previous employer -- and took out a partial money due to COVID hardship -- 401K is still active.

If I withdraw -- $90,000 on December 2020 -- then during tax season 2020 and before filing my 2020 taxes -- I repay $30,000 -- what will the tax burden be?
Will it be the full $90,000 or $60,000?

Thanks!